# Hyperledger transaction data loss upon VM restart

Tags: virtual-machine, hyperledger-fabric, restart

I have setup Hyperledger fabric network on a linux virtual machine. A business network is installed onto fabric network. I am able to perform transactions and update the blockchain accordingly.

When I restart my linux virtual machine, all the docker instances of fabric components such as peers, orderer, ca, cli are erased and hence I am not able to retain the transaction data as a result I am suffering a data loss.

Is there a way to retain the Hyperledger transaction data upon vm server restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use VMware to create your linux virtual machine, you can configure your vm setting to get persistent data storage, like mounting your container on a persistent disk, which is mounted from your physical machine. see [VM Hard Disk Storage](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_disks2.html) for reference.

For transaction data, if you mean your ledger, you can setup `volumes` parameter to link your disk and container disk. The ledger data located at `/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData` on peer container.

So you can add:

```
volumes:
- /<hard disk path>:/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData
```

on `docker-compose.yaml` file for peers.